# Failed to download and/or install client side AOP stack

Tags: jms

I am trying to establish JMS Queue connection.

But the Code where I'm getting error is

```
try {
    context = initialContext.getInitialContext();
    queueConnectionFactory = (QueueConnectionFactory) context.lookup("jms/TestQueueConnectionFactory");
    queue = (Queue) context.lookup("queue/"+userName);
    queueConnection = queueConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection();
    queueSession = queueConnection.createQueueSession(false, QueueSession.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    queueConnection.start();

    queueSender = queueSession.createSender(queue);
    TextMessage textMessage = queueSession.createTextMessage(userName+": "+enterTextText.getText());
    queueSender.send(textMessage);
    receiveTextText.insert("Me : "+enterTextText.getText()+"\n");
    enterTextText.setText("");
    enterTextText.setFocus();
    queueSender.close();
} catch (JMSException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (NamingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The line where I'm getting error is **queueConnection = queueConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection();**

connection-factories-service.xml will look as below

```
<server>
    <mbean code="org.jboss.jms.server.connectionfactory.ConnectionFactory"
           name="jboss.messaging.connectionfactory:service=TestQueueConnectionFactory"
           xmbean-dd="xmdesc/ConnectionFactory-xmbean.xml">
        <constructor>
            <arg type="java.lang.String" value="TestQueueConnectionFactory"/>
        </constructor>
        <depends optional-attribute-name="ServerPeer">jboss.messaging:service=ServerPeer</depends>
        <depends optional-attribute-name="Connector">jboss.messaging:service=Connector,transport=bisocket</depends>
        <depends>jboss.messaging:service=PostOffice</depends>
        <attribute name="PrefetchSize">150</attribute>
        <attribute name="DupsOKBatchSize">5000</attribute>
        <attribute name="SupportsFailover">false</attribute>
        <attribute name="SupportsLoadBalancing">false</attribute>
        <attribute name="SlowConsumers">false</attribute>
        <attribute name="JNDIBindings">
            <bindings>
                <binding>jms/TestQueueConnectionFactory</binding>
            </bindings>
        </attribute>
    </mbean>
</server>
```

The Exception what I'm getting is

> 

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to download and/or install client side AOP stack
    at org.jboss.jms.client.JBossConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(JBossConnectionFactory.java:199)
    at org.jboss.jms.client.JBossConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection(JBossConnectionFactory.java:101)
    at org.jboss.jms.client.JBossConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection(JBossConnectionFactory.java:95)
    at com.techm.jms.ChatWindow.sendMessageToQueue(ChatWindow.java:425)
    at com.techm.jms.ChatWindow$2.handleEvent(ChatWindow.java:184)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.closeWidget(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.WM_CLOSE(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.windowProc(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.windowProc(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.callWindowProc(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.windowProc(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.windowProc(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.callWindowProc(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.windowProc(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.windowProc(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessageW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessage(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at com.techm.jms.ChatWindow.open(ChatWindow.java:165)
    at com.techm.jms.ChatWindow.main(ChatWindow.java:129)
Caused by: org.jboss.jms.exception.MessagingNetworkFailureException: Failed to connect client
    at org.jboss.jms.client.delegate.ClientConnectionFactoryDelegate.createClient(ClientConnectionFactoryDelegate.java:313)
    at org.jboss.jms.client.delegate.ClientConnectionFactoryDelegate.org$jboss$jms$client$delegate$ClientConnectionFactoryDelegate$getClientAOPStack$aop(ClientConnectionFactoryDelegate.java:232)
    at org.jboss.jms.client.delegate.ClientConnectionFactoryDelegate.getClientAOPStack(ClientConnectionFactoryDelegate.java)
    at org.jboss.jms.client.ClientAOPStackLoader.load(ClientAOPStackLoader.java:75)
    at org.jboss.jms.client.JBossConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(JBossConnectionFactory.java:192)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.remoting.InvokerRegistry.loadClientInvoker(InvokerRegistry.java:453)
    at org.jboss.remoting.InvokerRegistry.createClientInvoker(InvokerRegistry.java:352)
    at org.jboss.remoting.Client.connect(Client.java:512)
    at org.jboss.jms.client.delegate.ClientConnectionFactoryDelegate.createClient(ClientConnectionFactoryDelegate.java:309)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.util.propertyeditor.PropertyEditors.mapJavaBeanProperties(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/util/Properties;Z)V
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.MicroSocketClientInvoker.mapJavaBeanProperties(MicroSocketClientInvoker.java:1280)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.MicroSocketClientInvoker.setup(MicroSocketClientInvoker.java:496)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.MicroSocketClientInvoker.<init>(MicroSocketClientInvoker.java:275)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.SocketClientInvoker.<init>(SocketClientInvoker.java:78)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.bisocket.BisocketClientInvoker.<init>(BisocketClientInvoker.java:164)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.bisocket.TransportClientFactory.createClientInvoker(TransportClientFactory.java:44)
    ... 48 more
```

Somebody please let me know, why I'm unable to create the connection